# The width of Profile Design Tri Stryke saddle (with cutout)?

Tags: saddle

I am interested in Profile Design Tri Stryke Saddle (with cutout), however there is no specs on the website, nor the manufacter answers my e-mail. So maybe somebody has this saddle and would be so nice and tell me what is the width of this saddle?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the width at its widest point, 122mm as best I can measure.

Comment: Thank you very much, despite this is a sad news for me ;-) From the photo I love this saddle, but I need something like 132 mm. Anyway, thank you once again.

Comment: No problem. These are very narrow.